# How to refer from other table in excel using vlookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

[image]
i have this table that has the information of each student from their age down to their BMI

The last column which is Nutritional Status should have a result whether the BMI is normal, wasted, obese etc.

below i have this table that has the result of the Nutritional Status depending on the age of a student.
[image]
how can I determine the nutritional status of a child using the table above?

Comment: What formula have you tried?

Comment: @tittaenälg i've used the vlookup to match the age from the first table and the second one but it still doesnt get the BMI because I forgot how to compare the BMI to the remaing rows of the specific row of the age.

Comment: Look into [`Index/Match`](http://www.randomwok.com/excel/how-to-use-index-match/). For your case, it's going to be better than `VlookUp()`

Answer (score 0):

Kent,

I think this will work for you. I tested it on line 1 for the 17.39 BMI and got "W" as planned. I assumed 2 sheets. Sheet 1 is the children table and sheet 2 is the BMI table. Just copy the formula into k4 and paste it down. If this works for you, please click button to accept the answer.

```
=IF(J4>INDEX(Sheet2!J:J,MATCH(Sheet1!F4,Sheet2!B:B,FALSE),1),"O",IF(J4>INDEX(Sheet2!I:I,MATCH(Sheet1!F4,Sheet2!B:B,FALSE),1),"OW",IF(J4>INDEX(Sheet2!G:G,MATCH(Sheet1!F4,Sheet2!B:B,FALSE),1),"N",IF(J4>INDEX(Sheet2!E:E,MATCH(Sheet1!F4,Sheet2!B:B,FALSE),1),"W",IF(J4>INDEX(Sheet2!C:C,MATCH(Sheet1!F4,Sheet2!B:B,FALSE),1),"SW","")))))
```

Have a good one!